# SAS data processing based on indexed value from another table

Tags: sas

I need suggestion on the aproach to the following (working in SAS enterprise guide 6.1)

I have 2 tables:
Table1: State, Date, Decimal_Value, Description(Char length 4); Table 1 has multiple descriptions, dates and values for each state

Table2: State, Year, Quarter, Description(Char length 4), Value;
Table 2 has multiple records for the same state and descriptions but with values changing depending on dates.

> Sample Tables:
>
> ```
> Table 1
> state      date    description    value 1
> IA        11/1/2013     A          -0.5
> IA        11/1/2013     B           4.5
> IA        9/1/2012      A           1.2
> IA        9/1/2012      B            5
> OH        6/1/2013      A           1.2
> OH        6/1/2013      B           -2
> ```

```
Table 2
State   Year    Quarter Description Value 2
IA      2013    4        A          40,350 
IA      2013    3        A          1 
IA      2013    2        A          150,000 
IA      2013    1        A          100,000 
IA      2012    4        A          5,000 
IA      2012    3        A          25,000 
IA      2012    2        B          50,000
```

For each observation from table 1, I want to be able to identify the date associated with the observation, then add up the values in table 2 that are within 1 year from that date for the specific state and description, save the sum, then repeat it for each record in table 1.

> Result I am looking for
>   Table 3
>
> ```
> state    date    Descr    Value 1    Sum of Value 2 (over a year)
> IA    11/1/2013    A    -0.5    =sum (Value 2 from (2013 quarter 4, 2013 quarter 3, 2013 quarter 2, 2013 quarter 1) for IA with desc = A)
> IA    09/1/2012    B     5.0    =sum(Value 2 from (2012 quarter 2, 2012 quarter 1, 2011 quarter 4, 2011 quarter 3) for IA with Desc = B)
> ```

I am stuggling to identify correct observation from table 1 in order to pick out dates, state and description to sum in table 2.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from your provided data and explanations to Table 3.  Why do you only have 2 rows?

Comment: Table 3 was just an example. The end result would have a row for each unique State,Date,Description record in table 1. I can work with the date in the table one to change it to Year and quarter, to make it easiear to lookup values in table 3

Comment: Also, I think that I could make a use of a macro to loop through the observations in table 1, but I am not sure how to identify the observations.

Comment: No, macros aren't the way to go here.  I'm mostly confused by your use of language here.  What difficulty are you having identifying observations in table 1?  Or, are you meaning, identifying which table2 observations match table1 observations?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the simplest answer is the best here: a SQL join.  Convert quarters to dates not the other way around- it's easier than converting things to quarters, I think, since `intck` is so friendly.  I show how to do it either in the dataset or in sql here.

```
data Table1;
input state $ date :mmddyy10. description $ value1;
format date DATE9.;
datalines;
IA        11/1/2013     A          -0.5
IA        11/1/2013     B           4.5
IA        9/1/2012      A           1.2
IA        9/1/2012      B            5
OH        6/1/2013      A           1.2
OH        6/1/2013      B           -2
;;;;
data table2;
input State $ Year Quarter Description $ Value2 :comma10.;
datevar = mdy(quarter*3,1,year);
format datevar DATE9.;
datalines;
IA      2013    4        A          40,350 
IA      2013    3        A          1 
IA      2013    2        A          150,000 
IA      2013    1        A          100,000 
IA      2012    4        A          5,000 
IA      2012    3        A          25,000 
IA      2012    2        B          50,000 
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
create table table3 as 
  select t1.state, t1.date,t1.description, t1.value1, sum(t2.value2) as value2sum
   from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
    on (t1.state=t2.state and t1.description=t2.description
        and 0 le intck('Quarter',mdy(t2.quarter*3,1,t2.year),t1.date) lt 4)
        group by t1.state, t1.date,t1.description,t1.value1;
quit;
```

You may want to fiddle with the equality some depending on exactly which records you want to include based on what value, and you may need to fiddle with the `intck` to define quarters how you want (you ask for 2012Q2 with 9/1/2012, that would be odd since 9/1 is definitely part of q3 normally; if that's not true in your company, use shift index in `intck` to adjust to your company's quarters).

Comment: I was definitely overthinking this (I was going to create temporary sub tables for each observation from table1, get matching records within date rnge from table 2, use proc means to add up values, then bring them back.). This is a more elegant aproach. Thank you.